# Connect to SQL Server without install program

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, installation, database-connection

Who can explain what happens?

C# program: click on button - got a list.

- VS 2017
- simple Windows form - one button, one grid
- Simple typed dataset - one table adapter, plain select from `Client` table
- Connection string to the remote(!) SQL Server

(there is no problem with code or connection string)

Before I did following: compile this program, copy `Release` folder to the client computer and run.

A few week ago, this program stopped working - probably after some Windows update:
it runs and when I press the button, it cannot connect to SQL Server (timeout, network-related or instance-specific error..., etc.)

But from the same computer, I can connect to SQL Server using `sqlcmd` utility or Management Studio.

This program works fine from developer and from some other computers. But on SOME clients - does not.

After research I found following:

- If I install program using ClickOnce or msi - it works
- If I then copy program to a different folder, it cannot find the server any more
- turning off firewall does not have any effect
- it still works fine on some other computers (without installation) even if program folder located on network folder.
- I play with sign/manifest - does not get any positive result.

I do not want to install/uninstall program on every client - I want just run it from flash/network/local copy.

How to run it? Any explanation or idea?

**Update:**

To simplify problem - there is the code:

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from clients", connection);
         command.Connection.Open();

         var zz = command.ExecuteScalar();

         MessageBox.Show("res " + zz.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: No, Remote server as I said: "Connection string to the remote(!) sql server."

Comment: Without seeing your connection string and some information about your network topology, it will be unlikely that anyone here can help you.

Comment: can you show us the connection string?

Comment: Data Source=DEVSERVER;Initial Catalog=dbName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass

Comment: there is no problem with connection string

Comment: Have you tried using Telnet or something similar to attempt a direct connection from the client computer to the DB server on port 1433? This may help determine if it is a network issue, firewall issue, or possibly IPsec.

Comment: sqlcmd and management studio connected fine, as well as program when it INSTALLED

Comment: Ok, just a guess but, sounds like your program has a positional dependence. When you move the code, something is not located relationally where the code can find it.

Comment: Check your solution/project files for an absolute path to something. Or a relative path to something that is not getting moved with your code.

Comment: program does not need anything - it is not position related. Program runs fine before. It most likely related to latest windows updates - looks like M$ does not allow to connect if program "is not installed"

Comment: You said if installed via ClickOnce or msi it runs fine, if it is moved from installation location it stops. This means it is not due to the Windows patch (or it wouldn't work from anywhere) but moving the code from the original installation location breaks it. This means it IS positionally dependent on something.

Comment: before april program was located on network an was ran from different clients. nothing was changed (same program, same network, same server), but some clients cannot connect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173089/discussion-between-parfilko-and-kevin).

Comment: Hmm. Is that a share on a Windows Server 2003 server? It could be this - _**Windows 10 update 1803 does not open network connections on executables files on SMBv1 share**"_ - see [this post](https://blog.mertech.com/windows-10-version-1803-breaks-some-shared-folder-applications) for more details.

Comment: thanks for reference - looks very similar. Except in my case local copy does not works as well, and we do not have win 2003